# OpenIAB Unity consume failure for amazon store

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am testing OpenIAB to upgrade from amazon IAP v1 to v2 in Unity. I am using the latest OpenIAB unity plugin.

I am able to query and purchase an IAP but then the call to OpenIAB.consumePurchase returns a failure callback. I am testing with App Tester on amazon.

I get the error below "original json invalid" after calling OpenIAB.consumeProduct(..)

> Original json is invalid:
>   {"itemType":"inapp","orderId":"","packageName":"","sku":"productexample","purchaseTime":0,"purchaseState":0,"developerPayload":"","token":"q1YqVrJSSi_OKynKLEhNzC4uyc9OzSvOTS3Ozc8vKMnMzzNU0lFKAaoxNDEzMzY3NzM2NjY1AoqVAsVyjD18zCMKClx9M4r83V3ySossdUtzygrzc4uC080KK_1dvHMTM8zNcrxCbYFaSpSsDGoB","originalJson":"","signature":"","appstoreName":"com.amazon.apps","receipt":”"}

I am having multiple other issues like I don't get back orderId or receiptID from queryInventorySuccess callback for the purchase that is already made. I see the valid productId but no orderId even though I see the receiptId on App Tester. What is the difference between Token, ReceiptId and OrderId?

Also what is the difference in using the below in manifest for android:name in receiver. Could there be a problem here?

```
<receiver android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.ResponseReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

compared to using

```
<receiver android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
            android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
            android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

If I use the first version in android manifest, then the app just crashes on start

Comment: why are you not using the built-in IAP/IAB in Unity?!?

Comment: @JoeBlow inbuilt Unity IAP/IAB? Do you mean from the asset store that uses prime31 or there is another one?

Comment: I am trying OpenIAB because it is a single platform solution for all stores. And it wraps around amazon IAP v2 which is what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just purely for the record Htcls,

Since about 2015 Unity3D now has

## in-app purchase built-in, as a integrated feature of Unity.

It is incredibly easy to use, compared to any previous approach for IAP/IAB.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAP.html

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

It is completely free and completely built-in to Unity.

This has been one of the most significant changes to App industry in some years.

Previously, achieving IAP/IAB (Apple/Google) was a HUGE effort on game titles. (The Prime31 plugins were popular for this.) Often it was more of a chore than making the actual game. It can now be achieved relatively simply ***WITH NO PLUGINS AT ALL*** inside Unity.

At this point it would be extremely unusual to use any other approach for IAP/IAB. It is an incredible advance and huge time saver that it is now built-in to Unity.

Regarding

## Amazon...

store coverage, follow the thread here

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-iap-store-guides-amazon-apple-google-play-windows.372647/

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QxHRo7DdjwNIUAm0Gb4J3EW3k1vODJ8dGdZZfJwetYk

Unity staffer "nicholasr" and others are actively answering all questions on the topic.

Consider this extremely simple code base which shows how the built-in IAP/IAB works

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-iap-store-guides-amazon-apple-google-play-windows.372647/page-3#post-2565610